# how to get fist class name from class like class="class1 abc" get 'class1'

Tags: jquery

i have li that has class name more then one ,

so i want to get first class name

```
  For Example

<li class="class1 smfont">1<li>
<li class="class2 smfont">2<li>
<li class="class3 smfont">3<li>
<li class="class5 smfont">5<li>
```

i want to get the class name only class1, class2, class3....
by jquery

i use

```
var $filteredData = $data.find('li[class=' + $filterType + ']');
```

but not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do it is:

```
var firstClass = $("li").attr("class").split(" ")[0];
```

`.attr("class")` gets the class names as a space-separated string, so the next step is to split that based on the spaces and just select the first element in the resulting array. You might want to trim it before splitting first if you don't control the HTML you're working with.

You can see a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/wXuFt/

Comment: Haha, trying that split is faster for me in FF and match is faster in Chrome. Good job Chrome I guess, I wouldn't have thought regex could be quicker.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this too http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/wXuFt/3/

```
var classOne = $('li').attr('class').match(/\w+/);
```

Comment: This is not just shorter. It's also more robust. Consider the case where class="  foo bar". mikel's answer does not extract 'foo'.

Comment: True, though it would if you trim first as I suggested. Split is marginally faster than regex too, though it's not going to make any noticeable difference. +1 from me for the elegance of it though :)

Comment: @mikel: Sorry. I hadn't seen that.

Answer (score 0):

A more robust version of eclanrs' answer:

var firstClass = ($("li").attr("class") || '').match(/\w+/) || '';

It handles the case where class isn't set and the variable name starts with a character, as it's supposed to. If there is no first class name, the variable will be set to the empty string. You may want to set it to `null` instead.

Comment: The variable is `null` if `class=""` so `var classOne = $("li").attr("class").match(/\w+/) || 'Whatever';` --> http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/wXuFt/5/